# sending IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> from View

Tags: c#, html, .net, asp.net-mvc, file-upload

I am sending Images to Action containing `IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase>`

Following is my model

```
public class M
{
    public IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> images { get; set; }
}
```

And action is

```
    [HttpPost
public async Task<ActionResult> ABC(CODE.M model)
{
    ...
}
```

And my file upload controls are three in numbers. like this

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })) 
{
    Main <input type="file" id="image1" name="images" />
    Image 2  <input type="file" id="image2" name="images"/>
    Image 3 <input type="file" id="image3" name="images" />
}
```

On fiddler its showing all images are getting posted but on action the `IEnumerable<HttpPostedFile>` showing count 0

On fiddler all three fileupload elements showing `images` as their name

Anyways I have also tried using like this

```
Main <input type="file" id="image1" name="images[0]" />
...
...
```

But obviously it must and is showing `null` on action when Post

My question is how should I name my fileupload elements?

Anyone came across this before?

Comment: The code you have shown will work fine. Is this a normal submit or are you using ajax?

Comment: @StephenMuecke you have the code using bitbucket its not ajax i made changes to Post action in the code that u have

Comment: ensure your form element is using the action="Post"

Comment: Have not had a chance to go through that yet :)

Comment: @cronixis all the other fields are populating model parameter in action.

Comment: Include `FormMethod.Post` on `BeginForm` too: `@using (Html.BeginForm("ABC", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))`. You may retrieve uploaded files using `Request.Files` with index array.

Comment: @Alex, Which controller and method in your BitBucket?

Comment: @StephenMuecke `lhController` `Post` action but what I posted here is not updated there

Comment: There could be model binding issues with generics. Consider using List in your view model:

public List<HttpPostedFileBase> images { get; set; }

Comment: @Alex. In your controller, first check if `Request.Files` contains values

Comment: @StephenMuecke Count is 0. why is that?

Comment: Your overload of `BeginForm` is adding enctype as a route value, not a html attribute

Comment: @StephenMuecke in fiddler it showing that posted values

Comment: @StephenMuecke you are right. thanks it's working

Answer (score -2):

Instead of:

```
    public class M{  public IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> images { get; set; }}
```

use this :

```
    public class M{  public HttpPostedFileBase[] images { get; set; }}
```